# File path not saving in Android

Tags: android

So in my app, images are downloaded when purchases so I put them in the SD card, have to input a directory, will do that afterwards. But I need to access them later on whenever the user selects it.

```
filePath.setFilePath1(fileName.getPath());
```

Is the code I have for saving them in my FilePath class. It keeps returning null but I have use `Log.d(TAG, fileName.getPath());` and it brings back the path

```
 /storage/emulated/0/scrtwo.png
```

Which is this here. Anyone know why it's not being saved in my setter?

It's very messy at the moment, but I'll fix it.

```
public class FilePath {
public String filePath1;
public String filePath2;
public String filePath3;
public String filePath4;
public String filePath5;
public String filePath6;
public String filePath7;
public String filePath8;
public String filePath9;
public String filePath10;


public FilePath(){}

public String getFilePath1() {
    return filePath1;
}

public void setFilePath1(String filePath1) {
    this.filePath1 = filePath1;
}

public String getFilePath2() {
    return filePath2;
}

public void setFilePath2(String filePath2) {
    this.filePath2 = filePath2;
}

public String getFilePath3() {
    return filePath3;
}

public void setFilePath3(String filePath3) {
    this.filePath3 = filePath3;
}

public String getFilePath4() {
    return filePath4;
}

public void setFilePath4(String filePath4) {
    this.filePath4 = filePath4;
}

public String getFilePath5() {
    return filePath5;
}

public void setFilePath5(String filePath5) {
    this.filePath5 = filePath5;
}

public String getFilePath6() {
    return filePath6;
}

public void setFilePath6(String filePath6) {
    this.filePath6 = filePath6;
}

public String getFilePath7() {
    return filePath7;
}

public void setFilePath7(String filePath7) {
    this.filePath7 = filePath7;
}

public String getFilePath8() {
    return filePath8;
}

public void setFilePath8(String filePath8) {
    this.filePath8 = filePath8;
}

public String getFilePath9() {
    return filePath9;
}

public void setFilePath9(String filePath9) {
    this.filePath9 = filePath9;
}

public String getFilePath10() {
    return filePath10;
}

public void setFilePath10(String filePath10) {
    this.filePath10 = filePath10;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "FilePath{" +
            "filePath1='" + filePath1 + '\'' +
            ", filePath2='" + filePath2 + '\'' +
            ", filePath3='" + filePath3 + '\'' +
            ", filePath4='" + filePath4 + '\'' +
            ", filePath5='" + filePath5 + '\'' +
            ", filePath6='" + filePath6 + '\'' +
            ", filePath7='" + filePath7 + '\'' +
            ", filePath8='" + filePath8 + '\'' +
            ", filePath9='" + filePath9 + '\'' +
            ", filePath10='" + filePath10 + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

Comment: Show your model class code.

Comment: Updated it now.

Comment: have you set all path ?3

Comment: Just the path2.

Comment: Yeah I know that but I just want path2 to be not null at the moment

Comment: yes, but this is not correct way, you should be adding it to arraylist and than user it later according to position

Comment: So you are not getting your filePath1 using getFilePath1(() method?

Comment: I can get in the same activity I use .setFilePath1 but I can't in another activity.